# Using sed to add new line to .json file

Tags: json, bash, sed

I'm trying to add a line to a .json, but I've been having some trouble. The file currently has information like this:

```
{
"Direction": "down",
"Conversion": "Complete",
"Version": "v1.0.20170724"
}
```

I want to add new information so that the .json file looks like this:

```
{
"Direction": "down",
"Conversion": "Complete",
"Version": "v1.0.20170724"
"Files": ["path/to/file1/file1", 
          "path/to/file2/file2"]
}
```

I tried using this command, where I created a variable (file_list) that lists the paths of the two files:

```
sed -i '$s/}/,\n"Files":"${file_list}"}/' sample.json
```

But I ended up with this instead:

```
    {
"Direction": "down",
"Conversion": "Complete",
"Version": "v1.0.20170724"
"Files": "${file_list}"
}
```

Is there a way I can used sed to add a list of file paths to the file?

Comment: Any solution you create that uses `sed` to modify JSON will be brittle.  I'd suggest looking into `jq` (which is a bit like `sed` but meant for JSON), or just write a couple lines of `python`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular case, you could get away with

```
sed '$s%}%,"Files": '"${file_list}"' }%'
```

but any sed solution is going to be brittle (as above), painful, or both.

By contrast, here's a simple but robust solution using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) in a bash or bash-like context:

```
jq --argjson f "${file_list}" '.Files=$f'
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll start using the jq command in the future from now on.